# Android - How to stop webview from refresh when I swipe

Tags: android, webview, tabs

I have 3 tabs in actionbar : A, B, C. I want A Tab state to stay until I finish my application.

I have no idea How to stop webview from refresh when I swipe in actionbar tabs.
A->B->C, When I swipe from A to C, A's webview are reloaded.

Below are my codes. Can you help me? Thanks so much in advance! :)

tab1.java

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
        Context mContext;

         WebView web ;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
                web = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
                web.setWebViewClient(new WebClient()); 
                WebSettings set = web.getSettings();
                set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

                web.loadUrl("http://www.naver.com");

                return mainView;


        }


        class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit` to the maximum number of page you have.

**From the docs:** [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.